# Extracting integers from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp

I have a list like this:

```
fmt_string="I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a policy for 30 
yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees"
```

from the above list I removed stopwords and got this 
Now I have a list as following:

```
['smoker', 'male', '25', 'years', 'wants', 'policy', '30', 'yrs', 
'sum', 'assured', 'amount', '1000000', 'rupees']
```

from this list I want to extract just 25, 30 and 1000000, but the code should be something like 25 would be before or after years. 30 could either be after policy and 1000000 can be at any position

finally output should be like:

```
'1000000 30 25 male smoker'
```

I just want a robust code that wherever I find these values i return me a list like this.

Comment: Please, write your code.

Comment: Do you have an attempt at the problem?

Comment: In order to filter a string, getting only integer values you could use that line of code: `integer_values = [e for e in fmt_string.split() if isinstance(e, int)]`

Comment: what about regex! `re.findall(r'\d+', fmt_string)`

Comment: for value in d:
    if value == 'male':
        print value+1

Comment: i tried this code

Comment: @GeetanjaliBisht which code?

Comment: Edit your question, adding your code. There is no code in your previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

This should be helpful

```
import re
# Variation in places of the numbers in strings:
str1 = "I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a policy for 30  yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees"
str2 = "I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a for 30 policy  yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees"
str3 = "I am a smoker male of years 25 who wants a for 30 policy yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees"
str4 = "I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a for 30 policy yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees"

regex = r".*?(((\d{2})\s?years)|(years\s?(\d{2}))).*(policy.*?(\d{2})|(\d{2}).*?policy).*(\d{7}).*$"
replacements = r"\9 \7 \8 \3 \5"

res_str1 = re.sub(regex, replacements, str1)
res_str2 = re.sub(regex, replacements, str2)
res_str3 = re.sub(regex, replacements, str3)
res_str4 = re.sub(regex, replacements, str4)


def clean_spaces(string):
    return re.sub(r"\s{1,2}", ' ', string)


print(clean_spaces(res_str1))
print(clean_spaces(res_str2))
print(clean_spaces(res_str3))
print(clean_spaces(res_str4))
```

Output:

```
1000000 30 25 
1000000 30 25 
1000000 30 25
1000000 30 25
```

**Update**

The regular expression above *has some bugs*. While I trying to improve it, I noticed that it is inefficient and ugly as it parses each single character each time. We could do better if we stick to your original approach of parsing the words instead. So my new solution is:

```
# Algorithm
# for each_word in the_list:
#     maintain a pre_list of terms that come before a number
#     if each_word is number:
#         if there is any element of desired_terms_list exists in pre_list:
#             pair the number & the desired_term and insert into the_dictionary
#             remove this desired_term from desired_terms_list
#             reset the pre_list
#         else:
#             put the number in number_at_hand
#     else:
#         if no number_at_hand:
#             add the current word into pre_list
#         else:
#             if the current_word an element of desired_terms_list:
#                 pair the number & the desired_term and insert into the_dictionary
#                 remove this desired_term from desired_terms_list
#                 reset number_at_hand
```

Code:

```
from pprint import pprint


class Extractor:
    def __init__(self, search_terms, string):
        self.pre_list = list()
        self.list = string.split()
        self.terms_to_look_for = search_terms
        self.dictionary = {}

    @staticmethod
    def is_number(string):
        try:
            int(string)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False

    def check_pre_list(self):
        for term in self.terms_to_look_for:
            if term in self.pre_list:
                return term
            else:
                return None

    def extract(self):
        number_at_hand = str()
        for word in self.list:
            if Extractor.is_number(word):
                check_result = self.check_pre_list()
                if check_result is not None:
                    self.dictionary[check_result] = word
                    self.terms_to_look_for.remove(check_result)
                    self.pre_list = list()
                else:
                    number_at_hand = word
            else:
                if number_at_hand == '':
                    self.pre_list.append(word)
                else:
                    if word in self.terms_to_look_for:
                        self.dictionary[word] = number_at_hand
                        self.terms_to_look_for.remove(word)
                        number_at_hand = str()
        return self.dictionary
```

Usage:

```
ex1 = Extractor(['years', 'policy', 'amount'],
                'I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a policy for 30 yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees')
ex2 = Extractor(['years', 'policy', 'amount'],
                'I am a smoker male of 25 years who wants a for 30 yrs policy with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees')
ex3 = Extractor(['years', 'policy', 'amount'],
                'I am a smoker male of years 25 who wants a policy for 30 yrs with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees')
ex4 = Extractor(['years', 'policy', 'amount'],
                'I am a smoker male of years 25 who wants a for 30 yrs policy with a sum assured amount of 1000000 rupees')
pprint(ex1.extract())
pprint(ex2.extract())
pprint(ex3.extract())
pprint(ex4.extract())
```

Output:

```
{'amount': '1000000', 'policy': '30', 'years': '25'}
{'amount': '1000000', 'policy': '30', 'years': '25'}
{'amount': '1000000', 'policy': '30', 'years': '25'}
{'amount': '1000000', 'policy': '30', 'years': '25'}
```

I expect better performance now.

Comment: it is throwing error as: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Is it (not the regex) showing the error for the same input? I get error!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 27, in extract
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Does changing `number_at_hand = str()` to `number_at_hand = ''` help? I don't understand why you are getting this error. I wrote this code for python3.6 and also ran using python2.7.12. And I got no error. Did you change anything? Could you please share your code?

Comment: Share your code otherwise, it's difficult to understand what's going on there. Because I get no error while running the given code for 2.7 or 3.6 version of python.

Comment: If the answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it by clicking the gray check button.

Comment: yaa i just changed number_at_string=' ' and now its working fine

Comment: thanks for this...is it possible if you can explain what is happening in the following code?

Comment: Are there any particular statements that you don't understand? If so, which ones? Regarding the overall process, the `# Algorithm` is given in the answer.

Comment: And we should learn the norms of the community as newcomers. Please go through this [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score -1):

use `re` for `findall` occurances in list and `join` with comma `split` this to list and apply `reverse()` to list and then `join ' '` again

your data:

```
li = ['smoker', 'male', '25', 'years', 'wants', 'policy', '30', 'yrs', 'sum', 'assured', 'amount', '1000000', 'rupees']

temp=",".join([l for l in li if re.findall('1000000|30|25|male|smoker',l)]).split(",")

temp.reverse()
temp = " ".join(temp)
```

Output:

```
'1000000 30 25 male smoker'
```

Hope this answer helpful.

Comment: This answer is about as general as `print '1000000 30 25 male smoker'`.